# how to use {%extends%} from base template in python jinja2 when writing sql

Tags: jinja2

In my python project I have two sql files with a lot of overlap.
I would like to create a base.sql and extend other two sql's from this base.sql.
[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

test_jinja2.py

```
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader,Environment

with open('sql/sql1.sql', 'r') as sql_file:
    sql = sql_file.read()
    # folder where all sqls including base.sql is stored
    template_folder=template_folder=os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sql'
    )
    template = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(template_folder)).from_string(sql)
    print(template.render())
```

base.sql

```
select * from temp1;
{%block part1%} {% endblock part1 %}
```

sql1.sql

```
{% extends 'base.sql' %}

{%block part1%}
select * from temp2;
{% endblock part1 %}
```